# deployable wiki-based documentation

Tags: deployment, version-control, documentation, wiki, collaboration

I am looking for a wiki project that is editable by developers and can have comments and history, much like everything else, but also has the following features:

- A way to tag or version the wiki in an intuitive interface that any competent developer can use
- A way to deploy a tagged or versioned snapshot of the wiki with the option of stripping it of any editorial history.

The use case is to have a team of developers able to fluidly update documentation in the lifecycle of a project and have the necessary internal dialogs, but then have a way to package the documentation in a polished way so that it can be included with a commercial product.

The ideal solution, if this software exists somewhere, would be to have some type of facility so that you can do say, PDF output to send to a commercial printer or have a way to do custom templates depending on the parameters of the deployment.

Does any sage developer out there know of such software?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at GitHub's [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) which seems to fit your requirements quite well. They also support [a bunch of different markup alternatives](https://github.com/github/markup), and both Markdown and Textile have converters to PDF (and probably a bunch of the other markup choices as well).

Comment: Certainly looks capable of it; there's a few RCS locked wiki systems out there; this appears to be the best I've seen.  It falls short of any baked in deployment though; and although you can layer that on; it would be nice if it was a conscientious design goal.  I'll contact the author of the software.  Let me keep this open another day or so for possible other solutions though (commercial ones are ok!)

Comment: drats ... still no answer.  Here's an upvote though.