# Wikis with VCS backends?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, wiki

I've recently stumbled upon some wiki's which use version control systems for their backend, namely

1. [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) (git)
2. [Hatta](http://hatta-wiki.org/) (mercurial)

This seems like a pretty neat idea to me and I wanted to play around with one such wiki. I was wondering if the StackOverflow community has been using such wikis and could provide a list of some of these. If you've used multiple of these wikis, an objective comparison would be a bonus.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956822) but it doesn't seem to be asking the same thing.

**Edit**: [wikirial](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/wikirial) seems to be another such wiki. Uses mercurial.

Comment: One thing worth considering is that both git and Mercurial lock-on-write, so if all pages are in the same repository you can only be persisting one change at a time.  That's not a dealbreaker for light use, but it's a pretty big limitation for a large, popular wiki.

Comment: Gollum is more active than anything I've seen, since GitHub uses it. Plus it supports a lot of wiki syntaxes. I'd go with that one if in doubt. The only annoying thing is that it won't show your latest edits before you've committed them.

Answer (score 5):

[gitit](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) uses git as a backend and in fact can be completely controlled from a shell. It uses the awesome [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for rendering so that one can easily download wiki pages as pdf or LaTeX source.

Comment: gitit now also supports mercurial and darcs.

Answer (score 4):

[Ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) is a wiki with many different VCS backends.

Comment: What wiki markup does it support?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat It uses Markdown by default, but claims to support other markups as well. I didn't got it to work with reStructuredText, but this is some years ago, and it might got better.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Twiki uses RCS](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/RCS).

Comment: TWiki is a very mature wiki with lots of features, despite using the ancient RCS as VCS.  Foswiki (a fork of TWiki that is developing somewhat faster) also uses RCS - see http://foswiki.org/System/SystemRequirements, it can use external rcs program or internal pure Perl RCS (RcsLite).  All Foswiki data is held as flat files (.txt and .txt,v for RCS) so it's possible (with some extra scripting) to use Git to sync Foswiki data to and from clients, for offline usage.

Answer (score 2):

Well, arguably [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) would be the best match, because it's a VCS with a *built in* wiki.

*(That aside, prepare for your question to be closed, it's a bit too close to "please provide me a list of", which isn't muchly appreciated)*

Comment: +1. I'd never heard of Fossil before.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, it supports Markdown or its own wiki syntax.